# Export NDVI values from chart as JSON in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-index, chart

After filter OLI8 for a small area

```
var collectionFilter = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',4)
  .map(app);
print(collectionFilter)
```

And add NDVI band

```
var app = function (image)
{
//indice de vegetação
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
image=image.addBands (ndvi.rename('NDVI'));

  return image
}
```

I generate a chart using a click function and try to export as JSON format the values.

```
Map.onClick(function(lonlat){
  var pixel = ee.Geometry.Point([lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat])
  var collection = collectionFilter
    .select(
      ["NDVI"]
    )
    var options = {
        title : 'NDVI CHART VALUES'
      };

    var graph = (
    ui.Chart.image.series(
      collection,
      pixel,
      ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      30
    )
    .setOptions(options)
  );
      print(graph

  )

  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: collection,
    description:  'exporting in json format each click',
    fileFormat: 'JSON'
  });

})
```

But doesnt work. How can I do this? Here is the [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3c284fecd627e3f4ba276e046eb7747)

Answer (score 0):

The `ui.Chart.image.series` function works very well in visualizing rapidly pixel values at a certain point, but it outputs a chart which you cannot export using `Export.table.toDrive`. At the moment, you are trying to export a imageCollection as a table, what is probably not wat you want.

To get the NDVI values corresponding to the pixel [lat,lon] you clicked, you first have to use reduceRegion(s). Then you get the pixel information of a geometry.

```
  // make a feature collection (which you can export)
  var featureCollection = collection.map(function(image){
    return image.reduceRegions({collection: pixel, scale: 30, reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()})
    // Map over the new feature collection to add the system:time_start of the image
     .map(function(feat){
      return feat.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
    });
  }).flatten();
  print(featureCollection)
```

Then you can export that collection to you drive. Note that the format is GeoJSON and that you cannot use spaces in the name

```
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: featureCollection,
    description:  'exporting_in_json_format_each_click',
    fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'
  });
```

Note that I took the liberty to make you collection filter in such a way that it filters the collection on the point you clicked, so it should work anywhere around the world (as long as there are image present).
[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6334c1f289a1f39ccf28ba058e0c2c20)

Comment: Thanks to share the knowledge.